# How to make multiple layout for one screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make Screen in android with multiple layouts. Fox example On the top of the screen there is the header with image slider (this part is done) below that there will be a list view and below that there will be grid view.

**Activitymain.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.root.multipleview.MainActivity">

    <!--Header image-->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoStart="true"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <!--ListView Below header -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:height="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CustomLayout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#f1f3f7"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--Header image with slider-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerimg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <!--ListView Below Header-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textdesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textName"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**ListView.java**

```
    package com.example.root.multipleview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by root on 11/18/2017.
 */

public class ListView extends AppCompatActivity {
    int[] Images = {R.drawable.salad,R.drawable.salami,R.drawable.flour,R.drawable.salt,
            R.drawable.sandwich,R.drawable.sausage,R.drawable.seeds,R.drawable.cheese,R.drawable.shrimp,R.drawable.cupcake,R.drawable.cup,R.drawable.spices,R.drawable.cabbage
            ,R.drawable.spoon,R.drawable.apple,R.drawable.asparagus,R.drawable.cupcake,R.drawable.fish,R.drawable.corn,R.drawable.cupcake,R.drawable.spatula,R.drawable.olives
            ,R.drawable.garlic,R.drawable.taco,R.drawable.broccoli,R.drawable.cabbage};

    String[] Names = {"a","B","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};

    String[] Description = {"VVV","DDD","ddd","dddsa","ddsdsds","zsxx","wwwwq","ddwqK","EQWK","FgggFFF","FFFkklF","FghhFFF","FFhhFF","FFhhFF",
            "FFmmmFF","FgggFFF","FFFFbbb","FFFFfeee","gfffFFFF","FFFFfff","FFFgffF","FFFFfgffg","FFFfgfgfF","FFFgffF","FFFgfggdF","FFFFdssa"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        android.widget.ListView listView= (android.widget.ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();

        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textView_N = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            TextView textView_D = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textdesc);

            imageView.setImageResource(Images[i]);
            textView_N.setText(Names[i]);
            textView_D.setText(Description[i]);

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.root.multipleview;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        ViewPageAdapter viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter( this);

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);
    }
}
```

**ViewPageAdapter**

```
    package com.example.root.multipleview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by root on 11/18/2017.
 */

public class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Integer[] images = {R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.e,R.drawable.j,R.drawable.r,R.drawable.x,R.drawable.y};

    public  ViewPageAdapter(Context context){this.context = context;}
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate((R.layout.custom_layout), null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.headerimg);
        imageView.setImageResource((images[position]));

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;

        vp.addView(view, 0);
        return  view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

When I check this all layout separately it works but after adding in one layout it's not working. output screenshot is added

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBYMn.png)

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your description and from the image you provide what is not working. It sounds like you are asking about how to make the ListView show up in your Layout, but most of the code you posted is for the ViewPager for which you said "this part is done". Try to be more specific with your question.

Comment: I want many layouts on one screen, for example, In a screen has list view below that Grid view. In my case on the top of the page, i am showing a header below that I am trying to display list view and below to list i want to show Grid view. My header part is working but when i try to show list of item  that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make multiple layout for one screen?

my approach for this goal is using **Fragments**

how?

i do make a single main_layout and set a **FrameLayout** in order to put fragments with different layouts.so i have a screen with different layouts.

this is my best answer for your question .

Comment: I would like to thanks for the time and answering my question, can you please suggest some example or tutorial that will be very helpful, i am new in this.
Thanks

Comment: @Harsh ,about UI design?

Comment: Yes, i want to learn how to use multiple layouts in one screen

Comment: @harsh,unfortunately i have not any link in my mind to give you but i recommend you search Fragment about questions in stackflow.good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot @mr. AF.